# How to implement tab-dependent storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to store some data through `localStorage` so I can load it again in the same page of a web if this page is refreshed.

Imagine a user writing a comment, he refreshes the page and I want to load again the comment through `localStorage` so the user can keep editing his comment after that refresh.

The issue I'm facing is that, what if the user has multiple tabs open on the same page, writing different comments? How could I retrieve the correct information for one specific tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is exactly what you need. It behaves the same way as `localStorage`, but is dedicated to the page session. The downside of `sessionStorage` is that if the user will close the tab, he'll loose it.

So, depending on your use case you can use:

1. **Local Storage**, but if user has two tabs, one will override another;
2. **Session Storage**, but is user closes the tab, he'll loose data. And when he'll open the same page, he won't see his changes;
3. You can combine two storages: store to both and read from the **Session Storage** first. In that case user will have independent pages with safe refreshing, and in case he close the tab, he'll get the data from the **Local Storage** once he opens the same page again (if multiple pages were opened before that, he'll get the latest version).

See:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Storages</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="local">LocalStorage</label>
        <input id="local" value="" onkeyup="localStorage.setItem('value1', this.value)" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="session">SessionStorage</label>
        <input id="session" value="" onkeyup="sessionStorage.setItem('value2', this.value)" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="sessionBackedByLocal">SessionStorage backed by LocalStorage</label>
        <input id="sessionBackedByLocal" value="" onkeyup="[sessionStorage, localStorage].forEach(s=>s.setItem('value3', this.value))" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var local = localStorage.getItem('value1');
    if (local) {
        document.getElementById('local').value = local;
    }

    var session = sessionStorage.getItem('value2');
    if (session) {
        document.getElementById('session').value = session;
    }

    var sessionBackedByLocal = sessionStorage.getItem('value3');
    if (session) {
        document.getElementById('sessionBackedByLocal').value = sessionBackedByLocal;
    } else {
        sessionBackedByLocal = localStorage.getItem('value3');
        document.getElementById('sessionBackedByLocal').value = sessionBackedByLocal;
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete contents of `sessionStorage` when the user navigates back or forth on the same tab? So my persistent data is only present on `sessionStorage` when refreshing the page? Thank you

Comment: Sure, why not. You can listen for navigation events and call `removeItem`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Answer (score 1):

Just make a storage key unique. For example include a topic or replied comment id in it:

```
localStorage.setItem(`reply-to-${topic.id}`, comment.text);
```

You can use also `sessionStorage` that unique per a tab. But closing the tab will destroy it.

Comment: What if the different tabs are sketches aiming for the same topic or replying the same comment? I'm looking for something more similar to generating an unique identifier for a tab, which I don't think that's possible

Comment: @JaviAlbors - Yes, it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid

Comment: @JaviAlbors you can use sessionStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage but it's destroyed on a tab's closing

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev actually that was what I was looking for, I don't know how I didn't fall for sessionStorage earlier... Thanks!!!